# How to count an element that shows in either of two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently learning and this may be a simple case, but I can't seem to figure the solution.

I have a table that contains `stations` and a table of `trips` that tells a trip starts from one station and ends on another station.

Goal: Have a table that contains station id, station name, station region id, and a column that count how many times a station appears in startpoint or endpoint

Problem: The query result doesn't seem to match the actual count, tested from other queries.

Question: Can anyone please correct my query? Any inputs and suggestions are welcome and very much appreciated, I am currently learning.

The query that didn't match:

```
SELECT
    s.station_id,
    s.name,
    s.region_id,
    count(*) as num_of_trip
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` t
RIGHT JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` s ON t.start_station_id = s.station_id AND t.end_station_id = s.station_id
GROUP BY s.station_id, s.name, s.region_id
HAVING s.name = 'Paulus Hook' OR s.station_id = 3620 -- the stations that i used for testing the result
ORDER BY num_of_trip;
```

Test:
Paulus Hook Station = 1 trip, Station 3620 = 5 trips

Actual:
Paulus Hook Station = 50 trip (0 start, 50 end), Station 3620 = 483 trips (230 start, 253 end)

I chose right join because other joins that I know (left join and inner join) shows even less results (0 for Paulus Hook and 5 for 3620)

My test query, the result matches with another query that pulls up the trip list for each respective stations:

```
select
    s.station_id,
    s.name,
    s.region_id,
    (select count(*) from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` t where t.start_station_id = s.station_id) as start_station,
    (select count(*) from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` t where t.end_station_id = s.station_id) as end_station
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` s
GROUP BY s.station_id, s.name, s.region_id
HAVING start_station > 0 OR end_station > 0
ORDER BY start_station, end_station;
```

Comment: It seems that my wording for the goal was a little unclear and for that I am very sorry, yet i am still thankful for all responses as it expanded my knowledge on working with SQL. 

Both answers are actually true to what i was aiming to do, except that instead of 2 columns (startcount and endcount) i want it to be 1 column (sum of start+end). Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to figured it out, i realized i have not try cross join and i think thats the solution. Here is the changes i applied:

```
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` t
CROSS JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` s
WHERE 
    s.station_id IN (t.start_station_id, t.end_station_id)
```

Anyway, if there are any alternatives i am still open for inputs, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would exercise caution when using a `CROSS JOIN` as it is very memory intensive since for every record of one table, you are joining the entire table to each record. The Bytes Shuffled for your code was 1.78GB.

Here's my approach: I first want to take the larger of the two tables and summarize the data into a smaller table. So using common table expressions, I count the number of occurrences of the begin stations. Then do the same with the end stations. This creates two smaller tables that list each station with the number of  occurrences in each.

Then, I want to join those counts to the information from the stations table. I use a `LEFT JOIN` to the Stations table. I use a `LEFT JOIN` in case a `station_id` in the Stations table is not in my counts table.

```
WITH start_station_count as (
    SELECT
        start_station_id,
        COUNT(*) as start_count
    FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
    GROUP BY 
        start_station_id
),

end_station_count as (
    SELECT
        end_station_id,
        COUNT(*) as  end_count
    FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
    GROUP BY 
        end_station_id
)


SELECT 
    station_id, 
    name, 
    region_id,
    IFNULL(start_count, 0) as start_count,
    IFNULL(end_count, 0) as end_count
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` citibike_stations
    LEFT JOIN 
        start_station_count 
            ON 
                citibike_stations.station_id = start_station_count.start_station_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        end_station_count 
            ON 
                citibike_stations.station_id = end_station_count.end_station_id
WHERE
    start_count > 0 OR end_count > 0
ORDER BY 
    (start_count + end_count) DESC
```

This code should run faster and will Bytes Shuffled much much lower since it's not cross joining.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your question, this should give you station appearance counts, separated into two columns:

```sql
with valid_stations as (
    select
        s.station_id,
        s.name,
        s.region_id,
        sum(case when s.station_id = t.start_station_id then 1 else 0 end) as start_count,
        sum(case when s.station_id = t.end_station_id then 1 else 0 end) as end_count 
    from 
        `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` t
    join
        `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` s ON t.start_station_id = s.station_id or t.end_station_id = s.station_id
    group by 1,2,3
),
all_stations as (
    select 
       station_id,
       name,
       region_id,
       0 as start_count,
       0 as end_count
    from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` 
)

select 
   station_id,
   name,
   region_id,
   max(start_count) as start_count,
   max(end_count) as end_count
from (
    select * from valid_stations 
    union all 
    select * from all_stations
)
group by 1,2,3
order by station_id
```